# Adding additional signup fields to Clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, clearance

I'm new to rails, and I'm using the clearance gem for authentication. https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance

It works great with the email, and password fields. But how would I add extra fields such as address, and phone number.

Comment: jayk , i believe you can add more columns to users table.

Comment: as in the migration?

Comment: yes by normal migrations, did u tried that?